# Three maven project A depends on B, B depends on C, how to make C invisible to A on compile time?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

In a web application, my project A (Front end) has a dependency on project B (Business layer).

Project B has a dependency on project C (Repository layer).

Thus, a class located in project C (Repo) can be instantiated in project A (Front). But obviously I do not want this.

I tried to declare an exclusion in the project's A pom.xml to exclude project C while declaring the dependency on project B - but when the WAR is built, the project's C jar is excluded from the final WAR.

How do I exclude project C from project a at compile time but not at WAR build time or runtime ?

Comment: What is your goal? why you don't want your project during compile phase? how do you want satisfy required dependencies then?

Comment: The goal is about design. I do not want my developers to instantiate a class from the Repo layer in the Front project. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use an exclude, and add an explicit dependency on C in the pom of A with the scope `runtime`. That way, it won't be in the compile classpath, but should be in the war file.

Answer (score 0):

Project `A` should note project `B` as a dependency but exclude project `C`. The build of the WAR can then manually re-include project `C`.

Here's a sample dependency with exclusions.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xom</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```